# vb.net Is it better to do multiple OrElse's, or a single check if Mod = 0

Tags: vb.net, performance, boolean-logic, modulus

There are two easy ways to check whether a month is the first of the quarter.

The first way:

```
If month = 3 OrElse month = 6 OrElse month = 9 OrElse month = 12 Then
    'do stuff
End If
```

The second way:

```
If month Mod 3 = 0 Then
    'do stuff
End If
```

To me, they are both equally readable. Though they are functionally different, as long as month is known to be between 1 and 12 inclusive, they are the same logic. Which way should be used?

In the worst case, if `month = 12`, then there are four comparisons performed. Is doing a modulus and one comparison faster (not that it's a significant performance difference)?

Comment: The classic answer [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: You could also consider a `Select Case 3, 6, 9, 12`... unless performance is really an issue here, you'll end up with opinion-based answers

Comment: @Steve No, it's not important, but it bugs me. I like doing things the *best* way, and if both ways look readable, speed is my next concern. Is there a way to know what the instructions the compiler turns these statements into?

Comment: Using LinqPad and creating a very simple test program that embed these instructions in a stopwatch and run a loop for 10 million times incrementing a veriable at each true the results are MOD=39ms IF=43ms. (Optimizations off) The difference is stable for month=12 or month=3. Enablig optimizations run the two versions in identical time. So, as expected, for every practical use the two methods are indentical, MOD seems to be Insignificantly faster. If you try the same on LinqPad you could get the translation in Intermediate Language

Comment: Do whichever version conveys the logic most clearly. Your 'Mod' version conveys that there's something about being divisible by 3 - if this is important, then use this. Speed is unlikely to be an issue.

Comment: I agree with @DaveDoknjas...if it makes more sense in the code to use the `If` statement, where you are doing something because it's the 3rd, 6th, 9th, or 12th month, use that. If you are doing something because the number of the month is divisible by 3 evenly, and not because it's March for example, I would use the `Mod` statement.

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf I reckon you have the winning method there for readability *and* performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DaveDoknjas stated in the comments above, use the method which follows the logic more clearly.

If your logic determines that you must do something because the month is the 3rd, 6th, 9th, or 12th month in the year, use:

```
If month = 3 OrElse month = 6 OrElse month = 9 OrElse month = 12 Then
    'do stuff
End If
```

But, on the other hand, if you need to do something *because* the number of the month is evenly divisible by 3, use:

```
If month Mod 3 = 0 Then
    'do stuff
End If
```

The difference in performance would be so miniscule that it wouldn't be noticeable. In the end, they both evaluate to `True` when you need them to, so it's really down to preference and what you deem logical and readable.

Answer (score 5):

You express a desire to use a test which is both readable *and* performs well.

You have to be careful when designing a test for performance: if you only have a comment as the part to be "executed" then in release mode it is likely to be optimised away completely, i.e. the test will not be in the final code which is run and you will not be timing that test.

You must put some operation in which cannot be optimised away, and does not swamp the timing. I have used an assignment from a value which is likely to be in a processor register, or at least in the processor cache, at the time it is used.

So, your test could look like

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        ' set up plenty of test data
        Dim rand As New Random
        Dim nTestMonths = 10000
        Dim testMonths(nTestMonths - 1) As Integer
        For i = 0 To nTestMonths - 1
            testMonths(i) = rand.Next(1, 13)
        Next

        ' time a lot of tests
        Dim sw As New Stopwatch
        Dim nTests = 100000

        Dim dummyVar As Integer

        ' run the tests in one order...
        sw.Restart()
        For i = 1 To nTests
            For j = 0 To nTestMonths - 1
                If testMonths(j) = 3 OrElse testMonths(j) = 6 OrElse testMonths(j) = 9 OrElse testMonths(j) = 12 Then
                    dummyVar = testMonths(j)
                End If

            Next
        Next
        sw.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)

        sw.Restart()

        For i = 1 To nTests
            For j = 0 To nTestMonths - 1
                If testMonths(j) Mod 3 = 0 Then
                    dummyVar = testMonths(j)
                End If

            Next
        Next
        sw.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)

        ' this test takes about nine times longer than the others
        ' so it is commented out.
        'Dim quarterStarts As New List(Of Integer) From {3, 6, 9, 12}

        'sw.Restart()

        'For i = 1 To nTests
        '   For j = 0 To nTestMonths - 1
        '       If quarterStarts.Contains(testMonths(j)) Then
        '           dummyVar = testMonths(j)
        '       End If

        '   Next
        'Next
        'sw.Stop()

        'Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)

        sw.Restart()

        For i = 1 To nTests
            For j = 0 To nTestMonths - 1
                Select Case testMonths(j)
                    Case 3, 6, 9, 12
                        dummyVar = testMonths(j)
                End Select
            Next
        Next
        sw.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)

        ' now run the tests in a different order...
        Console.WriteLine("Tests in reverse order...")
        sw.Restart()

        For i = 1 To nTests
            For j = 0 To nTestMonths - 1
                Select Case testMonths(j)
                    Case 3, 6, 9, 12
                        dummyVar = testMonths(j)
                End Select
            Next
        Next
        sw.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)

        'sw.Restart()

        'For i = 1 To nTests
        '   For j = 0 To nTestMonths - 1
        '       If quarterStarts.Contains(testMonths(j)) Then
        '           dummyVar = testMonths(j)
        '       End If

        '   Next
        'Next
        'sw.Stop()

        'Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)

        sw.Restart()

        For i = 1 To nTests
            For j = 0 To nTestMonths - 1
                If testMonths(j) Mod 3 = 0 Then
                    dummyVar = testMonths(j)
                End If

            Next
        Next
        sw.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)

        sw.Restart()
        For i = 1 To nTests
            For j = 0 To nTestMonths - 1
                If testMonths(j) = 3 OrElse testMonths(j) = 6 OrElse testMonths(j) = 9 OrElse testMonths(j) = 12 Then
                    dummyVar = testMonths(j)
                End If

            Next
        Next
        sw.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)
        Console.ReadLine()


    End Sub

End Module
```

which results in something like

```
10.047
18.001
6.722
Tests in reverse order...
6.463
17.604
10.254
```

So you can see that The_Black_Smurf's suggestion of using a `Select Case` statement has both very good readability *and* happens to be the fastest.